# how to concat two json objects in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, json, object

I have the following in an angular controller:

```
var jsonOne = $cookies.get('test');
// console logs {"domain":"localhost","zip":33333}

var jsonTwo = angular.toJson($scope.formData);
// console logs {"id":"210","name":"sam"}

var final = $.extend(jsonOne, jsonTwo);
// console logs [object object]
```

My goal is to get:

```
var final
// console logs {"domain":"localhost","zip":33333, "id":"210","name":"sam"}
```

I'm asking under angular because when I try it in a static html document it works fine, but for some reason it wont work in angular. Any ideas?

Comment: Define "won't work". What is the code, what is the input, what is the expected output, what is the actual output (or error)?

Comment: the expected outcome is for it to log {"domain":"localhost","zip":33333, "id":"210","name":"sam"}, instead it logs [object object]

Comment: You answered 1 of the 4 questions. Answer the 3 others. You didn't post any code that logs anything.

Comment: jsonOne and jsonTwo are not objects. They are strings. angular.toJson() takes an object and transforms it to a JSON string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be your use of `angular.toJson`, which [from the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson) serializes inputs as a JSON string. Using a string with `angular.extend()` won't work as you want.

Try to retrieve your elements without serializing them as a string - it seems like you might already have the objects and don't need to use `.toJson`.

Once you have your two objects, use `angular.extend()` to combine them.

```
var first = { "A": "B" };
var second = { "C": "D" };

var third = angular.extend(first, second);

console.log(third);
// in chrome it logs { A: "B", C: "D" }
```